# Julia graphs, dijkstra_shortest_paths

Tags: graph, julia

I would like to have expandable graph, being able to add vertices and edges, and run `dijkstra_shortest_paths` algo.
I am not able to find right way to define graph so that `dijkstra_shortest_paths` would work.
Below is my attempt.

```
using Graphs
g1= graph(ExVertex[], ExEdge{ExVertex}[], is_directed=false)
dist_key = "dist"
v1 = add_vertex!(g1, "a")
v2 = add_vertex!(g1, "b")
v3 = add_vertex!(g1, "c")
e12 = add_edge!(g1, v1, v2)
e12.attributes[dist_key]=1.0
e13 = add_edge!(g1, v1, v3)
e13.attributes[dist_key]=1.0
e23 = add_edge!(g1, v2, v3)
e23.attributes[dist_key]=1.0
epi = AttributeEdgePropertyInspector{Float64}(dist_key)
dijkstra_shortest_paths(g1, epi, ["a"])
```

Error message:

```
dijkstra_shortest_paths has no method matching   dijkstra_shortest_paths(::GenericGraph{ExVertex,ExEdge{ExVertex},Array{ExVertex,1},Array{ExEdge{ExVertex},1},Array{Array{ExEdge{ExVertex},1},1}}, ::AttributeEdgePropertyInspector{Float64}, ::Array{ASCIIString,1})
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this has got two close votes and a -1 (I just upvoted to counteract), its a perfectly reasonable question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the problem is the `["a"]` - you have to refer to the actual vertex "manually", i.e.

```
julia> sp = dijkstra_shortest_paths(g1, epi, [v1])
julia> sp.parents
3-element Array{ExVertex,1}:
 vertex [1] "a"
 vertex [1] "a"
 vertex [1] "a"
julia> sp.dists
3-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.0
 1.0
 1.0
```

Works for me.